# Set property of derived class on base class' instance

Tags: c#

I have a base class like this:

```
class Document {
    int number {get; set;}
    double sum {get; set;}
}
```

... and two derived classes:

```
class Bill : Document {
    double advance {get; set;}
}

class Quote : Document {
    double discount {get; set;}
}
```

At compile time, I know that I'll be dealing with an object of type `Document`. However, it's only at runtime that I know whether it will be a `Bill` or a `Quote`.

I need to perform specific operations depending on the type, e.g.:

```
if (myDoc.GetType() == typeof(Bill)) {
   myDoc.advance = 1000; //<-- can't find "advance"
}
```

.. but I can't compile like that as the properties of the derived class is not accessible from a base instance.

What is the proper way of doing that?
Here's a [fiddle to play around](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cbY8h8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myDoc.advance` can only compile if the compiler can tell at compile time that `myDoc` is a `Bill`. Otherwise, `myDoc` is just a `Document` and that type does not have an `advance` member.

Doing a type check like that will not modify the static type of `myDoc`. Instead, you would have to type cast it into a `Bill` first:

```
Bill myBill = (Bill)myDoc;
myBill.advance = 1000;
```

Note that instead of using `GetType()` which checks the exact runtime type, you should be using the `is` operator to verify that `myDoc` is a `Bill`. You can even use the newer pattern matching syntax from C# to make this nicer:

```
if (myDoc is Bill myBill) {
    myBill.advance = 1000;
}
```

Finally, please note that the common convention is to write properties in C# in PascalCase (i.e. `Advance`, `Number`, `Sum` and `Discount`).

Also note that class members are *private* by default, so you still wouldn’t be able to access those properties. So you would have to add a `public` in front of the property definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for going the extra-mile with naming conventions and accessors!

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is a good way to handle this if you are using C# 7.0+

```
if(myDoc is Bill bill)
{
    bill.Advance = 1000;
}
else if(myDoc is Quote quote)
{
    quote.Discount = 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast it:

```
if (myDoc.GetType() == typeof(Bill))
{
    ((Bill)myDoc).advance = 1000;
}
```